# Which flag should I use to report a dead link?

Tags: discussion, flags, broken-link

In this [workflow engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905389/workflow-engine-for-net) question, [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/905441/1743811) contains a [dead link to WorkflowGen](http://www.workflowgen.com/workflow/home/workflow_software_p401_EN_Y.htm). I want to flag this answer but I don't know which flag I should use for dead links. Can I choose *Other* and just comment "Dead link"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First ask the answerer to update/delete the link. If he doesn't take any action or doesn't respond for sometime (say two days), then (especially for this answer) you can remove the dead link yourself. You don't need to flag this post since it is not a *link only* answer.

Comment: All good advice. The only thing I would add is if you can fix the link yourself, go ahead and do it! This site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. No need to waste your time and the answerers' time with comments if it's a simple fix.

Comment: +1 for CodyGray: If it's a blog post moved to a new permalink (not so "perma" now, are you?) update it, otherwise it's often possible to find the most recent version at http://archive.org

Comment: I don't see how removing a dead link *improves* the post in any way. Replace it with a working one or add a comment saying it doesn't work anymore.